# How to display a Google Maps with Qt + QGIS

Tags: qgis, google-maps, qt

I am developing an application with Qt + QGIS. It will have a map component to be rendered by QGIS. The map needs to contain a base layer with Google Maps tiles and additional layers with data loaded from local files.

Is this possible with Qt + QGIS?

As far as I understand, displaying Google Maps data requires using the Google Maps JavaScript API. In Qt, one can have a browser component, where the map can be displayed. I'm not sure if this is a good approach, specifically because of projections problems and lack on synchronization with map layer and the other layers. See also this question: [Overlaying Google Map in standalone PyQgis application?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121005/how-to-overlay-google-map-in-a-standalone-pyqgis-application)

I couldn't find clear answers in the extensive searches I have done.

Comment: There are at least two QGIS plugins that cover this issue. Have you looked at them?

Comment: Yes, I have. But as far as I understand, those are for the QGIS application, and not for to be used in standalone applications, like this one.

Comment: You can use QgsXyzTileDataItemProvider class https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/92af1dacafe2d4ad661fef5d5544b704d428a686/src/providers/wms/qgswmsdataitems.h#L167

Comment: Thanks to pointing this, @DmitryBaryshnikov. As I have read somewhere else, the QGIS application code is a good tutorial - but I wouldn't know where to look at.